# Homological vs. homotopical connectivity

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, connectedness

There are two closely-related measures of connectivity of a topological space:

- **Homotopical connectivity** is the largest $n$ such that all homotopy groups up to and including the $n$-th one are trivial;
- **Homological connectivity** is the largest $n$ such that all reduced homology groups up to and including the $n$-th one are trivial.

They are related by a theorem of Hurewicz (taken from Alan Hatcher's topology book):

[image]

The theorem implies that, for a simply-connected space, the homotopical connectivity equals the homological connectivity.

My question is what happens when the space is not simply-connected? Are the two measures of connectivity equal in that case too? If not, what is an example of a topological space in which the homological connectivity is different than the homotopical connectivity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a space is not simply connected, its first homotopy group is non-zero, so the homotopical connectivity is zero. Meanwhile, the simpler Hurewicz theorem says that the first homology group is the abelianization of the first homotopy group. If this is non-trivial, both connectivities are zero. So, to find a counter-example, take your favorite group $G$ with trivial abelianization and any topological space with fundamental group $G$. One particular example of such a space is discussed in example 2.38 of Hatcher's book. In fact, the example there is acyclic, i.e. has infinite homological connectivity, so the two connectivities can be as unequal as theoretically possible without an assumption of simple connectedness.

Comment: Thanks! Is it always true that the homological connectivity is at least as large as the homotopical connectivity?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Yes. If the homotopical connectivity is $0$, this is trivial, and if the homotopical connectivity is $\ge1$, the space is simply connected and they are equal.